# photo gallery using Composite c1 cms

Tags: content-management-system, gallery, c1-cms

I just started using composite C1 CMS. And I have built one sample site where I need to build the photo gallery. I was able to upload single single picture but confused to create gallery. I also need to upload multiple pictures one at a time.

So,I will be very thankful to the solution

Comment: Hey guys i got the solution.Just we need to add the composite package for the image gallery.

Answer (score 4):

**Upload multiple files**

You can upload multiple pictures using the "Upload Multiple" command instead of the "Upload File" command in the media archive. Here is how to:

1. On your computer select all the images you with to upload and make a ZIP file with them
2. In the C1 Console, on the Media perspective, execute the "Upload Multiple" command on the desired folder
3. In the dialog, browse to the ZIP from step 1 and upload.

UPDATE: This is now documented at http://users.composite.net/C1/Image-Media/Upload-Multiple-Files.aspx

**Getting an Image Gallery**

There are pre-build galleries you can use. Consider using one of those rather than building your own.

Here is a **[guide on adding a blog and gallery to Composite](http://docs.composite.net/C1/Getting-started/Guide/Adding-Blog-and-Gallery.aspx)**. The gallery used here uses Picasa (an online service for picture storage). If you want to upload your pictures to the CMS instead, install one of these packages:

- [Composite.Media.ImageGallery.ADGallery](http://docs.composite.net/Composite.Media.ImageGallery.ADGallery)
- [Composite.Media.NivoSlider](http://docs.composite.net/Composite.Media.NivoSlider)
- [Composite.Media.ImageGallery.Slimbox2](http://docs.composite.net/Composite.Media.ImageGallery.Slimbox2)

They are all available as C1 Packages you can install, evaluate and uninstall if you dislike them.